# Kohana 3.3 : required field

Tags: validation, kohana, kohana-orm, kohana-3.3

I'm using Kohana 3.3.
I use ORM for validation form, by determining some rules.

I would like to make a radio button required. I have three options, and no one can be checked in advance.

I've searched on web, no doc.

Someone has an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use not_empty rule:

```
public function rules()
{
        return array(
            'your_field_name' => array(
                array('not_empty'),
            ),
        );
}
```

Comment: I was looking for keyword 'required', or 'checked', but no results. Thank you.